# Can't get term id for category archive

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, terms

I am trying to get the term_id of the current category archive.
On the category archive, when I `var_dump($wp_query)`

```
object(WP_Query)#1189 (55) {
  ["query"]=>
  NULL
  ["query_vars"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["tax_query"]=>
  NULL
  ["meta_query"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["date_query"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["queried_object"]=>
  NULL
  ["queried_object_id"]=>
  NULL
  ["request"]=>
  NULL
  ["posts"]=>
  NULL
  ["post_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["current_post"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["in_the_loop"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["post"]=>
  NULL
  ["comments"]=>
  NULL
  ["comment_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["current_comment"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["comment"]=>
  NULL
  ["found_posts"]=>
  int(0)
  ["max_num_pages"]=>
  int(0)
  ["max_num_comment_pages"]=>
  int(0)
  ["is_single"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_preview"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_page"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_archive"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_date"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_year"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_month"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_day"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_time"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_author"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_category"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_tag"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_tax"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_search"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_feed"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_comment_feed"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_trackback"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_home"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_privacy_policy"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_404"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_embed"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_paged"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_admin"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_attachment"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_singular"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_robots"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_favicon"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_posts_page"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_post_type_archive"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["query_vars_hash":"WP_Query":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["query_vars_changed":"WP_Query":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["thumbnails_cached"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["stopwords":"WP_Query":private]=>
  NULL
  ["compat_fields":"WP_Query":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "query_vars_hash"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "query_vars_changed"
  }
  ["compat_methods":"WP_Query":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "init_query_flags"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "parse_tax_query"
  }
}
```

I have a custom post type `item` that uses the `category` taxonomy.

In the admin bar, I get `Edit Category` and it loads the correct link with the term ID like so: `/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=category&tag_ID=22&post_type=post`

Thanks!

Comment: Try: `global $wp_query; $the_category = $wp_query->get_queried_object(); var_dump( $the_category );` that should get you the info you need at the category/archive template level, but not within the loops of those templates.

Comment: You can just use `get_queried_object()` on its own.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with Elementor, which is where I built the category template. I was updating the query filter, which is why I needed the term id. When I test with category.php, the wp_query object works.

Answer (score 0):

To get `term_id` of current taxonomy, use the following code snippet

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well on the category.php and when added to the query filter: `
``
add_action( 'powerpack/query/item-cat', function( $query ) {
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    $query_vars = array(
        'post_type' => 'item',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'cat'   => $queried_object->term_id,
        'posts_per_page' => 150,
        'orderby'   => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    foreach($query_vars as $key => $value) {
        $query->set( $key, $value );
    }
} );
```